# Development tools for java mobility

Tags: java, mobile

I am beginner in java mobile, I download Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 as emulator but I need something to edit my code I mean write and edit source code to implement. which development tools I need ? and which is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Eclipse with Mobile Tools for Java (MTJ). I have not tried Eclipse Pulsar build yet (I always get Eclipse for Java EE and install MTJ if required as my main work is on Core Java and Web Projects), but that might do the job as single IDE download. Other alternative is Netbeans IDE which is also very popular.

Answer (score 0):

I use [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org) and have no complatints about it so far. It comes with all tools you need to develop applications for Java ME: it has Sun SDK 3.0, ProGuard and automated obfuscation, built-in libraries, visual designer for fast UI creation, game builder and other useful features.